# Parsing a table within a table using JSOUP

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am trying to extract some data from a table by parsing the HTML using jsoup.

Here is an example,

```
String tableHtml =
     "<table>
           <thead>
                <tr><th> 
                     <table>
                         <tr><td>asdf</td></tr>
                     </table> 
                     <table>
                          <tr><td>asdf</td></tr>
                     </table>
                 </th></tr>
           </thead> 
           <tfoot>
                <tr><td>
                   THE TEXT I WANT TO GET
                </td></tr>
           </tfoot> 
     </table>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(tableHtml);
Element table = doc.select("table").first();
Element r = table.select("tfoot").first(); // I get NULL here/// WHY???
System.out.println("-----------" + r.text());
```

I get null pointer exception !

However if I remove one of the inner tables, I don't get an exception and it works. Also if I changed the tag `<th>` to `<td>`, it works. Strange behavior.
This is just an example of real html that I am trying to parse.
I would appreciate if anyone can point me out why I am getting this exception. Thank you.

NOTE. Please assume that I cannot modify the HTML. I just want to parse it as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe instead of using HTML parser (which apparently doesn't fully support this kind of nesting tables) use XML parser. Try with

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(tableHtml,"",Parser.xmlParser());
Element table = doc.select("table").first();
Element r = table.select("tfoot").first(); 
System.out.println("->" + r.text());
```